# Push Notification Service for WPF based desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf, push-notification

I need help to choose a Push Notification Service for my WPF desktop based app. I was checking on Google's Firebase, Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) etc but they all speak in context of App based environment  i.e. iOS, Android or WP. Further more they have documented references for Web Apps using JavaScript.

Now i am stuck to find one which is compatible for my desktop based WPF + C# App.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check out [signalr](https://www.asp.net/signalr), if that suits your needs.

Comment: But using signalr having limitation of having Windows Server and we are using PHP as server side technology.

Comment: Have you checked Azure Notification Hubs?

Comment: Yes, I just checked but have documentation for UWP and Windows Phone not for Desktop Based app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't work unless you convert your app (No matter if it's WPF/MFC/other desktop tech) to UWP/Store app.

Fine details are listed here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx

**Reason:** WNS Push notification API doesn't support DualApiPartition attribute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationchannelmanager

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by Wolfgang you can use Azure Notification Hubs. If you install the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs you can then use that to subscribe to notifications. It requires a minimum of .Net 4.5, so long as your WPF application is targeting that or higher you should be fine.

Comment: Have you tried what you're suggesting? After some googling this is the only reference I found that suggests that it is possible to use Azure Notification Hub with WPF. Just looking for confirmation before I spend the time on a proof of concept. Thanks!

Comment: I recall doing a small demo to check if it would work and it does so worth cracking ahead with your own proof of concept

Comment: @KatoMan did you ever finish your POC?